# changing the url in html

Tags: php, html, session, url

my problem is whene i deploy my web site in the server i changed all my url to match the local host in the server then wriet the /pages my question is there simple way to do this next time ?

```
 <!--footer maroc soir-->
<div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-left: 120px;">
       <h5><b>GROUPE LE MATIN</b></h5> 
        <ul class="unstyled">
           <h6> <li><a href="http://localhost/tuto-ms-template/historique.php">Historique</a></li></h6>
           <h6><li><a href="http://localhost/tuto-ms-template/nos-valeurs.php">Nos Valerus</a></li></h6>
           <h6><li><a href="http://localhost/tuto-ms-template/mot-president.php">Mot du Président</a></li></h6>
           <h6> <li><a href="http://localhost/tuto-ms-template/organigramme.php"">Organigramme</a></li></h6>
       </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: no need to use the entire URL because when you do this it tends to link to the client's localhost, which might be nonexistant.

Comment: the responsible of the server in my wwork place told me to use session but i didnt get it :p

Comment: sai phani how can i do that pleas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If u are using php

put the fix path to a seperate php file

Example : In srever_path.php write

```
<?php
$server_path = "http://localhost/";
?>
```

and include in all your php like this

```
<?php
include("srever_path.php");
?>

<!--footer maroc soir-->
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-left: 120px;">

             <h5><b>GROUPE LE MATIN</b></h5> 
            <ul class="unstyled">
               <h6> <li><a href="<?= $server_path?>tuto-ms-template/historique.php">Historique</a></li></h6>
               <h6><li><a href="<?= $server_path?>tuto-ms-template/nos-valeurs.php">Nos Valerus</a></li></h6>
               <h6><li><a href="<?= $server_path?>tuto-ms-template/mot-president.php">Mot du Président</a></li></h6>
               <h6> <li><a href="<?= $server_path?>tuto-ms-template/organigramme.php"">Organigramme</a></li></h6>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

now to have to change your server_path in one php file
hope it will work

Comment: yes that what im lokin for just chaging one line thanks all of you for the help ^^

Answer (score 0):

try to use relative path in anchor so no need to change site url on different server.

```
<a href="historique.php">Historique</a>
```

Comment: yeah you can every server use no need to any changes

Answer (score 0):

depending on what folder the files are located and what url you use to connect the website try this:

for connecting `http://example.com/`

```
<!--footer maroc soir-->
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-left: 120px;">

             <h5><b>GROUPE LE MATIN</b></h5> 
            <ul class="unstyled">
               <h6><li><a href="tuto-ms-template/historique.php">Historique</a></li></h6>
               <h6><li><a href="tuto-ms-template/nos-valeurs.php">Nos Valerus</a></li></h6>
               <h6><li><a href="tuto-ms-template/mot-president.php">Mot du Président</a></li></h6>
               <h6><li><a href="tuto-ms-template/organigramme.php"">Organigramme</a></li></h6>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

and if you are connecting connecting `http://example.com/tuto-ms-template/` try this:

```
         <h5><b>GROUPE LE MATIN</b></h5> 
        <ul class="unstyled">
           <h6><li><a href="historique.php">Historique</a></li></h6>
           <h6><li><a href="nos-valeurs.php">Nos Valerus</a></li></h6>
           <h6><li><a href="mot-president.php">Mot du Président</a></li></h6>
           <h6><li><a href="organigramme.php"">Organigramme</a></li></h6>
        </ul>
    </di
```

Answer (score 0):

if your using linux machine, following command will help you..

```
grep -rli 'localhost' * | xargs -i@ sed -i 's/'localhost'/'example\.com'/g' @
```

But better to use relative urls, rather than absolute url, like others said. You can use this command to remove all occurance of localhost/path also by making sed command's target string empty

localhost with path

```
grep -rli 'localhost\/path' * | xargs -i@ sed -i 's/'localhost\\/path'/'yoursite\.com\\/path'/g' @
```

**Keep a back up before trying this command** :(